# Order a list based on a fixed format

Tags: c#

```
int[] OrderedListToFollow = {1,2,4,5}
int[] ListB = {2,3,4,8,9}
```

Based on the two lists above I need to sort ListB based on the order defined in OrderedListToFollow. Since 3,8,9 are not part of the OrderedListToFollow those can appear in any order, so the acceptable solutions could have any of the following :

```
int[] ListB = {2,4,3,8,9}
int[] ListB = {2,4,8,3,9}
int[] ListB = {2,4,9,3,8}
```

I tried doing this as follows but it does not order it :

```
ListB = ListB.OrderBy(id => OrderedListToFollow.ToList().IndexOf(id)).ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

The order above works but it places the items not present in OrderedListToFollow  first and then the remaining.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not order it"? What *does* it do? (I'd expect it to put 8, 3 and 9 at the *start*, as IndexOf will return -1...)

Comment: "does not order it" meaning it keeps ListB as it is...

Comment: I doubt that very much. I suspect you've misdiagnosed it. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad it was ordering based on -1 earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your sorting method is that the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns -1 if the item is not found. Thus, all your items which exist "outside" the given ordering scheme are placed at the beginning of the collection because they get an index of -1.

You could try using a conditional to return the index if found and the current index otherwise:

```
var c = ListB.Count();
ListB = ListB
    .OrderBy(id => OrderedListToFollow.Contains(id)
        ? OrderedListToFollow.ToList().IndexOf(id)
        : c + 1    // This will always pace invalid objects at the end
    );
```

Comment: This still has the same problem, I solved it using : .OrderBy(id => OrderedListToFollow.Contains(id)
        ? OrderedListToFollow.ToList().IndexOf(id)
        : ListB.ToList().Count() + 1
    );

Comment: In the else condition you still have IndexOf(id) which would mean -1 and placing them at the beginning, if I use Count + 1 I just make sure they get placed at the very end (the non-existing ids)

Comment: can you fix the code above and I will mark it an answered

Comment: Count() would place said objects at the end, but IndexOf preserves their existing indexes by indexing against the source collection. will update, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, it was already working apart from putting the results at the beginning. To fix this, I'd add an extension method:

```
public static int IndexOfOrMax(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    int index = source.IndexOf(item);
    return index == -1 ? int.MaxValue : index;
}
```

Also note that you don't need to call `ToList` on `OrderedListToFollow` - currently you're calling that a *lot*, which is very inefficient. With the above extension method in place, you can use:

```
int[] orderedListToFollow = {1,2,4,5};
int[] listB = {2,3,4,8,9};
listB = listB.OrderBy(id => orderedListToFollow.IndexOfOrMax(id)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
int[] OrderedListToFollow = {1,2,4,5};
int[] ListB = {2,3,4,8,9};


List<int> ListC = new List<int>();
ListC.AddRange(OrderedListToFollow.Where(p => ListB.Contains(p)));
ListC.AddRange(ListB.Where(p => !OrderedListToFollow.Contains(p)));
```

This will give you a result like this :

> 2
>   4
>   3
>   8
>   9

Comment: The logic works but it has too much performance impact, that's why I selected answer from Aravol

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Join and Except, the benefit being that they're both ~O(n) operations (due to both using Hashtables in their implementations). This snippet hinges on the assumption that OrderedListToFollow is indeed ordered.

```
int[] OrderedListToFollow = new[]{1,2,4,5};
int[] ListB = new[]{3,4,8,2,9};

var existing = from o in OrderedListToFollow
               join l in ListB on o equals l
               select l;

var other = ListB.Except(OrderedListToFollow);

var result = existing.Concat(other);
```